Flutter iOS Debugging Error: "Could not resolve package dependencies"
I’m facing an issue while debugging a Flutter app on my physical iPhone in vscode. The app runs successfully when executed without debugging in Xcode, but debugging fails with the following error:
Xcode build done. 93.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Uncategorized (Xcode): Could not resolve package dependencies:
downloaded archive of binary target 'absl' from 'https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/bin/abseil/1.2024011602.0/rc1/absl.zip' does not contain a binary artifact.
downloaded archive of binary target 'openssl_grpc' from 'https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/bin/grpc/1.65.1/rc1/openssl_grpc.zip' does not contain a binary artifact.
downloaded archive of binary target 'grpcpp' from "https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/bin/grpc/1.65.1/rc1/grpcpp.zip" does not contain a binary artifact.

fatalError 3
Error launching application on itsupport’s iPhone.


Why does this error occur specifically when debugging?
How can I resolve the dependency issues with the Firebase binary targets?

